# Is there anyway to use a custom domain in Express.js

Tags: node.js, express, dns

I was making my website, and bought a domain for it. However, I can only send my web app (`Express.js`) to localhost, and not to my domain. I've checked everywhere, and found no results. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: This is really not a stackoverflow question as it has to do with network configuration not actually writing code and has nothing specific to do with Express at all.  Your domain needs to be hooked up to the public IP address of your server.  That IP address needs to be accessible from the network you are on (typically open to the internet) so not blocked by any firewall.

Answer (score -1):

```
var connect = require('connect')
var serveStatic = require('serve-static')
var vhost = require('vhost')

var mainapp = connect()

// add middlewares to mainapp for the main web site

// create app that will server user content from public/{username}/
var userapp = connect()

userapp.use(function (req, res, next) {
  var username = req.vhost[0] // username is the "*"

  // pretend request was for /{username}/* for file serving
  req.originalUrl = req.url
  req.url = '/' + username + req.url

  next()
})
userapp.use(serveStatic('public'))

// create main app
var app = connect()

// add vhost routing for main app
app.use(vhost('userpages.local', mainapp))
app.use(vhost('www.userpages.local', mainapp))

// listen on all subdomains for user pages
app.use(vhost('*.userpages.local', userapp))

app.listen(3000)**strong text**
```